# open file linux eclipse c error after getchld

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, signals, creation

im just trying to open a file.
i have done it for 100 times, and then I sent SIGCHLD signal to other processes and i think right after that i couldn't open that file anymore.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define FLAGS IPC_CREAT | 0644
int main()  {
int res =open("results.txt",FLAGS);
if(res== -1) { printf("error!!")}   //prints it every time
return 0;}
```

..it suddenly just happened.. help ???

Comment: The first thing to do would be to figure out the specific cause of the error, using errno and/or strerror().  [This page](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/perrorman.html) should be helpful.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, `IPC_CREAT` is not a valid mode of `open`. Did you mean to use `shmget` ?

Comment: when printing an error, output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  and output the message the OS thinks is the problem.  I.E. use: `perror()`, not `printf()`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  Never use tabs for indenting.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is visible even with variable width fonts.

Comment: the `IPC_CREAT` should be: `O_CREAT`

Comment: do not `#include` header files that are not being used.  I.E. the posted code should not have the statement: `#include <signal.h>`

Comment: the call to `printf()` is missing a trailing semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing something strange with the flags. I think your intention is as per below code:

```
#define FLAGS O_CREAT
#define MODE 0644
int main()  
{
    int res =open("results.txt",FLAGS,MODE);
    if(res== -1) { printf("error!!");}   //prints it every time
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this answer does not compile due to the missing trailing semicolon on the call to the `printf()` statement

Answer (score 0):

the following code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. properly calls the `open()` function
3. properly displays the error message
4. does not `#include` header files that are not used
5. consistently indents the code
6. follows the axiom: `only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.
7. separates code blocks (for, if ,else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line
8. uses a proper signature for the `main()` function (the empty parens in the posted code means that any number of parameters, including 0 parameters, are allowed
9. code should not return 0 *success* when an error occurs so using `exit( EXIT_FAILURE )`

And now the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <unistd.h>  // open()
#include <fcntl.h>   // O_CREAT

#define FLAGS O_CREAT
#define MODE 0644

int main( void )
{
    int res =open("results.txt", FLAGS, MODE);
    if(res== -1)
    {
        perror( "open for results.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }   

    return 0;
}
```